# Compare two csv files compare the difference and write difference in csv file?

Tags: shell, powershell, csv, scripting

Say I have two csv files

**Old.csv**

**name,place,value**

abc,us,1

**new.csv**

**name,place,value**

xyz,us,2

abc,us,1

**output**

**name,place,value**

xyz,us,2

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (import-csv -path old.csv | select -exp name) -DifferenceObject (import-csv -path new.csv | select -exp name)
```

With this code, I'm not sure how and where the new output(the difference) is written. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even simpler than that probably.

```
$Old = Import-CSV Old.csv
$New = Import-CSV New.csv

$New | ?{$Old -notmatch $_} | Export-CSV Output.csv -notype
```

Output is:

```
name                          place                         value
----                          -----                         -----
xyz                           us                            2
```

That work for you?

Comment: Is there a way to replicate this beautiful simplistic code in python?