# Windows Powershell: How to compare two CSV files and output the rows that are just in either of the file but not in both

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, join

I have a file **first.csv**

```
name,surname,height,city,county,state,zipCode
John,Doe,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075
Jack,Yan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119
Jill,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075
Steve,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119
Alpha,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075
```

and **second.csv**

```
name,surname,height,city,county,state,zipCode
John,Doe,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075
Jack,Yan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119
Jill,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075
Steve,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119
Bravo,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119
```

I want to compare the rows of both **first.csv** and **second.csv** files and output the rows that are either in **first.csv** or **second.csv** but not in both.

So the **output.csv** should have

```
Alpha,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075
Bravo,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119
```

There are quite a few similar questions but the output is not exactly what I want.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you want to compare specifically between both CSVs ? And, what have you tried ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250797/compare-two-csv-files-compare-the-difference-and-write-difference-in-csv-file

Comment: Doesn't seem you want this question answered, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: That's quite helpful. I have edited the question. Hopefully, it's better now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filea = Import-Csv C:\Powershell\TestCSVs\group1.csv
$fileb = Import-Csv C:\Powershell\TestCSVs\group2.csv

Compare-Object $filea $fileb -Property name, surname, height, city, county, state, zipCode | Select-Object name, surname, height, city, county, state, zipCode | export-csv C:\Powershell\TestCSVs\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm using the all the fields to compare and sort here but you can specify the unique value(s) that you're wanting to use to match the rows.

## output

```
"name","surname","height","city","county","state","zipCode"     
"Bravo","Tan","220","Phila","Riverside","PA","9119"             
"Alpha","Fan","120","jefferson","Riverside","NJ","8075"
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what I am missing but I tried your commands but the output CSV just has "name" text in it.

Comment: @polapts try my edit

Answer (score 0):

Getting the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) (everything that is unrelated) from two lists is actually a quite common use in comparing objects.
Therefore, I have added this feature ([#30](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object/issues/30)) to the [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)).

For this for this specific question:

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\First.csv |OuterJoin (Import-Csv .\Second.csv) |Format-Table

name  surname height city      county    state zipCode
----  ------- ------ ----      ------    ----- -------
Alpha Fan     120    jefferson Riverside NJ    8075
Bravo Tan     220    Phila     Riverside PA    9119
```